# Angular 5, ionic 2 JSON refresh only works once

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I generated a JSON file and added it to one of my providers "people.ts":

```js
getPeople(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get("https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10")
}
```

Then I wrote 2 functions which should reload and add more JSON objects once they are called (ionic infinite scroll and doRefresh functions) below:

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
              public service: People)
  {
    this.service.getPeople().subscribe( data => {
      this.people = data.results
    });
  }

  doRefresh(e) {
    this.service.getPeople()
    this.service.getPeople().subscribe( data => {
      this.people.unshift(...data.results),
        Error => console.log(Error),
        () => e.complete()
    });
  }
  doInfinite(e) {
    this.service.getPeople()
    this.service.getPeople().subscribe( data => {
      this.people.push(...data.results),
        Error => console.log(Error),
        () => e.complete()
    });
  }
```

**The problem is that both work only once(they refresh and add) and the circle never stops spinning. What could I do ?**

[Photo of spinning circle in app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQEwS.png)

And that's where I call them:

```
<ion-refresher (ionRefresh)="doRefresh($event)">
    <ion-refresher-content>

    </ion-refresher-content>
  </ion-refresher>

  <ion-infinite-scroll (ionInfinite)="doInfinite($event)">
    <ion-infinite-scroll-content>

    </ion-infinite-scroll-content>
  </ion-infinite-scroll>
```

Comment: why are you calling `this.service.getPeople()` twice in `doRefresh` and  `doInfinite` ?

Comment: doRefresh when I scroll Up (it adds some new json data) , and doInfinite when I scroll down, it add automatically.

Comment: I know that but you have called it twice in each method? may copy paste mistake.

Comment: I call it twice, for do refresh and do infinite, where do you see more ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace your `doRefresh` and `doInfinite` like below

```
doRefresh(e) {
this.service.getPeople().subscribe( (data) => {
  this.people.unshift(...data.results);

}, (Error) => console.log(Error), () => e.complete());


}



doInfinite(e) {
    this.service.getPeople().subscribe(  (data) => {
      this.people.push(...data.results);        

    },(Error) => console.log(Error),() => e.complete());
  }
```